# Mixed UTF-16 and ASCII string

Tags: c, encoding

I have mixed ASCII and UTF-16 strings, the main problem is that, I need to somehow split it as each character in string.
for example assuming we're under Windows and (in most cases) default encoding is UTF-16:

```
const wchar_t msg[] = L"AД诶B";
```

I have defined total of 4 characters.

```
A = 2 bytes.
Д = 2 bytes.
诶 = 4 bytes.
B = 2 bytes.
```

I need to take 4th character from the string (ASCII B), but if I do msg[4] it will split Chinese keyword and will return wrong result. How can I solve that without any additional libraries?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry for wrong title, I'm totally tired.

Answer (score 3):

As you've already discovered, UTF-16 is really a variable-width encoding. So, you will have to scan across the string to perform accurate character indexing.

Luckily, it is very easy to tell if a character is part of a multi-word sequence: the only multiword sequences in UTF-16 (as currently defined) are *surrogate pairs*: a word in the range [D800-DBFF] followed by a word in the range [DC00-DFFF]. So, when you encounter such a sequence, treat it as a single character.

This may work for your needs:

```
UChar32 utf16_char_at_index(const wchar_t *s, off_t index) {
    while(1) {
        if(s[0] >= 0xd800 && s[0] <= 0xdbff) {
            /* First half of surrogate pair; check next half */
            if(s[1] >= 0xdc00 && s[1] <= 0xdfff) {
                /* surrogate pair: skip or return */
                if(index == 0) {
                    return ((s[0] - 0xd800) << 10) | (s[1] - 0xdc00);
                }
                s += 2;
                index--;
                continue;
            }
            /* Otherwise, decoding error...may want to flag error here */
        }
        if(index == 0) {
            return s[0];
        }
        s++;
        index--;
    }
}
```